# "setTimeout" and "for"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display one "Hi." every second, but following code does 7 "Hi." one second.
What should I do?

**script.js**

```
var main = function(){
for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
setTimeout(function(){$('div').append("Hi.");},1000);
};

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code says it should create 7 timeouts, all of which resolve after 1000ms. Consider changing that part.

Comment: you might not need a loop for that? what is the usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop creates 7 timeouts that complete 1 second from when the loop completes. You could multiple the timeout by the index of the loop.

```js
var main = function(){
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){$('div').append("Hi.");}, i * 1000);
    };
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Alternately, you can use `setInterval` and a counter to clear the interval on the 7'th run. This would be better for longer loops.

```js
var main = function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('div').append("Hi.");
        if(++counter >= 7) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `setTimeout` when you have `setInterval` option?

Comment: @Tarik Both ways will work. I've added a setInterval example.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make use of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`.

You can use `setInterval` with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) to accomplish what you need.